# Click event listener not working on a component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

HTML:

```html
<ul>
    <item
      v-on:click="boom"
      v-bind:product="item"
      v-bind:key="item.id"
      v-for="item in items"
     ></item>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
Vue.component('item', {
    props: ['product'],
    template: '<li><a href="#">{{ product.name }}</a></li>',
});

let app = new Vue({
    el: 'ul',
    data: {
        items: [
            { id: 0, name: 'penda' },
            { id: 1, name: 'harla' },
            { id: 2, name: 'calar' },
        ],
    },
    methods: {
        boom: function (e) {
            alert('Aha!');
        }
    }
});
```

Everything is rendered fine, but the `boom` event listener is never fired. Do you know the reason why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `.native` to get `v-on:click.native="boom"`

More details can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)

Comment: My understanding is this: the root instance was trying to listen to an event from the child component. But, if the child component doesn't tell the root instance about it (via `emit`), the event listener will never be triggered. Does this mean that `native` events don't follow this pattern?

Comment: As I understand you can create custom click like `$emit('click', e)` and in this case, you will have the conflict between native and custom `click` events. To prevent situations like that '.native' modifier was introduced.

Comment: `.native` tells vue to add the listener for the child root node (`li` in your example). If you try to combine my code with the code from @dagalti's answer you can find two listeners for the click event on the same element. https://jsfiddle.net/fc0p9jq2/

Comment: Thank you. I'm still confused as to why it's possible to access the parent's `boom` when using the `native` modifier. I guess this is to ensure nothing gets passed from child components without explicitly saying so.

Answer (score 4):

Use `@click.native="boom"` as @Pvl answered. OR bind the custom from parent component and emit from child. please run & check the below code.

```js
Vue.component('item', {
    props: ['product'],
    template: '<li @click="clickevent($event)"><a href="#">{{ product.name }}</a></li>',
    methods:{
clickevent(e){
this.$emit('componentclick', e)
}
}
});

let app = new Vue({
    el: 'ul',
    data: {
        items: [
            { id: 0, name: 'penda' },
            { id: 1, name: 'harla' },
            { id: 2, name: 'calar' },
        ],
    },
    methods: {
        boom: function (e) {
            alert('Aha!');
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<ul>
    <item
      @componentclick="boom"
      v-bind:product="item"
      v-bind:key="item.id"
      v-for="item in items"
     ></item>
</ul>
```